# What do you call a GUI widget that slides out from the left or right?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, settings, design-theory, widget

In mobile applications, many times you have the main content taking up the entire screen but there is a settings page also. To reach the settings page you can to put your finger on the left or right and swipe to the center.

For example in Google Maps on Android, when you put your finger on the left edge of the screen and swipe right you get a GUI widget. On the widget, you can then change settings like enable satellite imagery, enable traffic, etc etc. Then when you are done with the settings and wish to return to the application's content you swipe from right to left to close the settings widget.

**What do you call this GUI widget that slides out from the left or right?**

Comment: ... I didn't know that you could just swipe to open the settings on Google Maps. Always pushed the "hamburger" instead...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe you are referencing a [Navigation Drawer](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#).

Comment: indeed it is :)

Comment: +1. More generically, the pattern is also called "off-canvas."

Comment: *Slide In Panel* is another generic term for this, while not being quite *that* generic.

Comment: I prefer slide in panel or perhaps hidden sidebar, since they aren't always about navigation. E.g. the right hand panel on stack mobile is more a report with links than a nav imo. Plain sidebar have been a desktop browser thing for ages. Blender has toggleable panels on either side of the main view that feel related too, can't remember what they call them.

Answer (score 12):

All the product owners I have interacted with have called this either a fly-out nav or, less formally, a hamburger menu. Although w3 considers fly-outs to be more akin to header drop-down menus: [W3 Fly-out Menus](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/)

It's usually punctuated with the hamburger looking menu icon and supports slide gestures when available as you described.

Consider this [gallery of hamburger menus on vtldesign](https://vtldesign.com/web-strategy/website-design-development/hamburger-icon-flyout-menu-website-navigation/) and the sample image below:

**Collapsed**

[image: Sample Hamburger Menu Collapsed]

**Expanded**

[image: Sample Hamburger Menu Expanded]

Answer (score 0):

On [TED](http://ted.com), we refer to the left / right slide-in menus as Shoji menus, after the [Japanese sliding panels found IRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dji). You can see them [on our site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dji) by collapsing the viewport, or this example at [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/shoji-layout-slide-in-side-panels-for-xs-viewports).

You can see a screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I like the name, but sadly it has **poor recognition on Google** -- the first result for _shoji menu_ is a sushi restaurant, and even _shoji menu UI_ has poor results. The person you are communicating with will likely **have a hard time understanding you**, at least until this term spreads a bit.

Answer (score -3):

It may be a Carousel (but be aware of those - http://uxmovement.com/navigation/big-usability-mistakes-designers-make-on-carousels/).